# Why does the Footpath Killer stutter?

Tags: criminal-minds

In the S01E02 Gideon relates how he confronted a killer who stutters saying he knew the cause but he refuses to tell the cause to the rest of the team because they should find it out for themselves.

I didn't watch the whole episode and could not find the answer on internet.

Comment: [Real life backstory:](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Speech-Language_Pathology/Stuttering/Famous_People_Who_Stutter/Serial_Killers_and_Murder-Suicides) `After examining a series of killings near San Francisco area hiking trails in 1979, FBI psychological profiler John Douglas concluded that the Trailside Killer [David Carpenter] was a stutterer.`

Comment: @Darrick Herwehe - that is a bit different than figuring the "cause" of a stutter.  In the case you cited Douglas deduced that the killer might have a speech impediment based on the criminal behavior (attacked victims from behind, indicating that he lacked the confidence to interact face to face), not what might have caused a stutter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SPOILERS...

Elle figures it out at the end. Gideon does not know at all; he just told the killer that to buy himself time. Then he gets inside the killer's head, rattles him and gets the upper hand.

Quote from Gideon to Elle:

"I'll tell you what I do know about a stutter: I know how to provoke one."

Answer (score 1):

He stuttered because of embarrassment. Notice how he didn't stutter until Gideon humiliated him by making fun of his math skills.

Answer (score -1):

He stuttered because he was afraid.  He only stuttered two times.  The first was when he discovered that he was found out by a police or such (Gideon's gun).  the second time was when Gideon caused him to get angry.